# If I have a positive definite matrix X. How do i show that X$^2$ and X$^{-1}$ are also positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

To my understanding a positive definite matrix is a real symmetric square matrix where all eigenvalues are positive. 
Therefore for a matrix A and vector v

$Av = {\lambda}v$ where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of A

so $det({\lambda}{I_n} - A)=0$.

My next thought would trying to see how the formula changes when A is now A$^2$ and A$^{-1}$, but I'm getting nowhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another definition is that a symmetric matrix $M \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ is positive definite if and only if $v^T M v > 0$ for all nonzero vectors $v \in \mathbb R^n$.

Notice that 
\begin{align}
v^T A^2 v &= v^T A^T A v \\
&= u^T u \\
&= \|u\|^2
\end{align}
where $u = Av$.
If $v \neq 0$ then $u \neq 0$, so $\|u\|^2 > 0$. This shows that $A^2$ is positive definite.

We can show that $A^{-1}$ is positive definite by noting that
$$
v^T A^{-1} v = v^T A^{-1} A A^{-1} v = u^T A u
$$
where $u = A^{-1}v$. If $v \neq 0$ then $u \neq 0$, so $u^T A u > 0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot this really clears it up, i forgot about that definition but it makes perfect sense

Answer (score 1):

For a pos.def. matrix $A$, you have (necessary and sufficient) that for any real vector $v$, that $v A v \ge 0$.

Now $ v A^{-1} A v = v (A^{-1} A A^{-1}) v =(v A^{-1}) A (A^{-1} v ) = u A u > 0 $.

$A^2$ is even easier: $v A^2 v = v A A v = (v A) (A v) = u^2> 0$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ with eigenvectors $v_1,\ldots,v_n$. Note that $$A^2 v_i = \lambda_i A v_i$ = \lambda_i^2 v_i$$ and that $$Av_i = \lambda_i v_i \Rightarrow A^{-1}v_i = \lambda^{-1}v_i$$ Therefore the eigenvalues of $A^2$ are $\lambda_1^2,\ldots,\lambda_n^2$ and the eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$ are $\lambda_1^{-1},\ldots,\lambda_n^{-1}$. This should be enough to prove that $A^2$ and $A^{-1}$ are positive definite.